# Several useAsyncData requests in nuxt 3 slow down the page completely

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I need to make several requests through useAsyncData at the same time and get a response without freezes when switching to other pages, but when I go to the page, there is a strong freeze.

I tried the same through the official. I do the documentation using await Promise.all in useAsyncData, but the answer is the same, there is a strong freeze, when I make one request, any of them works fine.

`const {data: stamps} = await useAsyncData(
'dataStamps',
() => $fetch(urls.stamp)
);

const {data: drivers} = await useAsyncData(
'dataDrivers',
() => $fetch(urls.driver)
);`

Comment: If possible, move those requests to client side, so the server serves the html, and then there, you can make requests to handle datas. But if there is not possible to move those to client, so make those requests faster, by configuring data fetching or adding cache .

Comment: @AliBahrami the data comes in a large format, so it would be more convenient to process it on the server side, you could think about the cache when the issue with data processing would be resolved, but now the problem is that when the data is loaded, the site freezes a lot, and there is no way go to another page because of this

Comment: You have to handle data separately and then use it in your app. Use pagination if possible. If not, move data fetching process in ClientOnly. That's all I cab say via provided information

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use useLazyAsyncData or use lazy mode for useAsyncData
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-lazy-async-data

```
const { data } = await useLazyAsyncData('data-stamp-driver', async () => {
  return await Promise.all([$fetch(urls.stamp), $fetch(urls.driver)])
})
```

OR

```
const { data } = await useAsyncData('data-stamp-driver', async () => {
   return await Promise.all([$fetch(urls.stamp), $fetch(urls.driver)])
}, { lazy: true })
```

Comment: That will not fix the problem